# In JavaScript, are there any security issues associated with FileReader?

Tags: javascript, security

Consider the following piece of code:

**(Partial) HTML:**

```
<input type="file" accept=".txt" id="theFile" class="button" />
```

**(Partial) JavaScript:**

```
$('#theFile').on('change', function(e){
    readFile(this.files[0], function(e) {
       var text = e.target.result;
    })
})
function readFile(file, callback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = callback
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

My question is, is there any security risk involved in the use of `FileReader`, particularly in this case, when deployed with `readAsText`? For example, what happens if the file chosen is not a .txt but something else? Is it possible for a malicious user to attack the hosting website in some way?

If it's relevant for the purposes of the question, the full code simply retrieves a text from a .txt file and prints parts of it on screen.

Any other detail or information required, I'd be happy to provide.

Comment: This is running on the clients machine, it can't effect server.   And even if it was malicious  your code above is just reading the text, not executing it.

Comment: That was my gut instinct too, but I wanted to make sure. Thanks; if you add your comment as an answer, I'd be able to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are fine here there is no security issues.

1. The code is been executed in the users browser not the server, so even if it was malicious, they would only be infecting themselves.
2. The code above is only reading the file as text, so even if it was malicious it won't be getting executed.

Were you do need to be careful when creating a website, is if you allow a user to upload malicious files, and then somehow allow them to execute them server side.  An example would be were a PHP website didn't have correct security, you allowed them to upload a bad PHP file and this directory was available via the website, the PHP file could then be executed server side by them just putting `www.mywebsite.com/upload/danger.php` into there browser.